# Tried converting a char to a string to place in a method; where am i going wrong?

Tags: java, for-loop, char, replaceall

I'm writing a code that would replace the lettering in a string with another letter. However, my current assignment wants the code in a particular format. I attempted the code below:

```
public String replaceLetter(String word, char letterToReplace, char replacingLetter)
{
    letterToReplace = Character.toString(letterToReplace);
    replacingLetter = Character.toString(replacingLetter);
    word = word.replaceAll(letterToReplace, replacingLetter);
    return word;
}
```

Please excuse any inefficiencies in the coding as I am still relatively new to programming in general. I also recently got into chars and strings more intensely,so there is much I do not know in terms of some of the rules or traits pertaining to them. Are the errors in my code illogical? The IDE I am currently using is an online one that has the sole purpose of collecting my assignment for grading. Whenever I compile the code above, it gives me errors such as a missing return statement, so I would not count it as reliable. The IDE itself is extremely limited, and cannot compile things such as switch statements, so I'd prefer if I could keep it as simple as possible. However, I have found that the IDE will recognize most correct coding. I did try to attempt the coding with a for statement:

```
public String replaceLetter(String word, char letterToReplace, char replacingLetter)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        char ca = word.charAt(i);
        if (ca == letterToReplace)
        {
            word = (word.substring(0,i)+ replacingLetter + word.substring(i+1));
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

But I also ran into errors.  Any help in correcting my syntax would be appreciated.

Comment: _"But I also ran into errors."_ What errors?

Comment: The compiler pointed out that my use of parentheses may have been incorrect or that my for statement was illegal. It has been known to do that, but I believe my error lies elsewhere.

Comment: The answer shows that if you use `toString`, the result is a `String` and you have to assign to a `String` variable.  Java is strongly typed, which means that you can't change the type of a variable by assigning something of a different type to it.  However, you don't really need to convert to strings, since Java has a `replace` that allows `char` arguments: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to assign your `Strings` created with `Character.toString` to your existing `chars`, then you're passing those `chars` into the `replaceAll` function (which doesn't accept `chars`, it needs `Strings`). Try changing your code to this:

```
    public String replaceLetter(String word, char letterToReplace, char replacingLetter)
    {
        String letterToReplaceAsString = Character.toString(letterToReplace);
        String replacingLetterAsString = Character.toString(replacingLetter);
        word = word.replaceAll(letterToReplaceAsString, replacingLetterAsString);
        return word;
    }
```

**Edit:** As ajb pointed out, you could also call `replace` (instead of `replaceAll`) passing in your original `char` perimeters, and skip the step of assigning your `Strings`. Note that `replace` will still replace all occurrences of the `char`:

```
return word.replace(letterToReplace, replacingLetter);
```

Comment: I see now, thanks for both pieces of advice. I'll keep them in mind for my next assignments.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your **letterToReplace** and **replacingLetter** variables are character type and you are assigning **String** to them as **Character.toString** method returns string.
Change the variable type to **String** and you will be good to go.